# Stop implicit conversion for C++98 and C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, type-traits, c++98

I have a templated class with a `get()` method which returns the type it is templated on. There's a bit more to it than that, but for simplicity the code looks something like:

```
Attribute<float> attr(0.0f);
float value = attr.get();
```

However, the following will also compile:

```
Attribute<float> attr(0.0f);
int value = attr.get();
```

I want the compiler to catch that, and tell me that I have an illegal conversion. A simple way of doing that is to create a new `Holder<T>` class which has a conversion operator to the type that it's templated on. The get method would work as follows:

```
template<typename T>
Holder<T> Attribute::get()
{
    return Holder<T>(m_value);
}
```

With the Holder class looking something like:

```
template<typename T>
class Holder 
{
    private:
        T m_value;
    public:
        Holder(T value) : m_value(value) {}
        //implicit conversion
        operator T() const { return m_value; }
};
```

(I've written this just in the editor and haven't tested it, but that should work-ish to do what I want in C++98)

```
Attribute<float> attr(0.0f);
// This should now not compile because we have no conversion from
// Holder<float> to int.
int value = attr.get();
```

The tricky bit comes when we move to C++11, I probably want to use auto, and suddenly, when I do:

```
Attribute<float> attr(0.0f);
auto value = attr.get();
```

`value` will now be of type `Holder<float>` which I don't want. Can anyone think of a way of allowing both to work, perhaps with some boost magic.

Comment: "implicit casting" seems to be an oxymoron.

Comment: Is it really an issue that `value` would be of type `Holder<float>`? Wouldn't it automatically convert to `float` when necessary?

Comment: You might want gcc/clang flag `-Wconversion`.

Comment: Also, you better test that returning `Holder<float>` actually prevents conversion to `int`. I have not been able to produce a compile error for the following line: `int value = attr.get();`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah... That's probably the simplest way, I'll just need to check that I'm not using implicit conversion elsewhere. I was just wondering if anyone could think of an 'in code' way of doing it.

Comment: @FlamFace Doesn't the answer I provided work?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I'm sure it would, but it's a bit cumbersome to type every time. What I really want is to be able to specify the type, and get an error if I get it wrong, which `-Wconversion` does.

Comment: @FlamFace While I understand what you mean, I disagree with you. You can always use typedefs to un-cumbersome it. Honestly it's a very weird excuse in C++ to claim that a solution is not usable just because you have to declare types systematically. You have to know also that this way I showed you is the standard STL way of forward defining types, e.g., a `vector<double>::value_type` is `double`. If you really think this is cumbersome, you should consider switching to Java, or something else that detects types better at run-time. Good luck!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I never said it was unusable, it just doesn't meet the parameters of the question I was asking.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis: What did you try? A private, templated conversion operator should capture all types that don't exactly match the public overload.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis Are you talking about in the `Holder` class? Sorry, I'm probably being stupid, but don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: @FlamFace I am indeed talking about the `Holder` class. As Ben Voigt noted, you need a second, templated, conversion operator to catch unwanted conversions. The implementation shown in your answer still allows `int value = attr.get()` to compile.

Comment: The trouble is, with the `Holder` class, I get no benefit in C++11 with auto. If, for example I template on a non-primative type, and I need to call a method of that type, I'll simply get a compiler error that my `Holder` object doesn't have have that method.

Comment: @FlamFace Valid point. Throwing out the `Holder<T>` class and using the `-Wconversion` compiler flag (or equivalent for your compiler) seems like the best and most elegant solution to your problem. Is that the strategy you have adopted in the end?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis So far. I'm still hoping that someone will come along and have a way of doing it using some templating magic, but for now, that's what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `typedef` inside the `Attribute` class as so:

```
typedef T value_type;
```

and then at the assignment part:

```
Attribute<float> attr(0.0f);
decltype(attr)::value_type value = attr.get();
```

This way you won't need that holder.

And if you insist on using that holder, you could do the same and extract `value_type` from the holder.

Comment: @Jarod42 true, but my solution eliminates all implicit conversions

Comment: There are no conversions with `auto`. And you would have implicit conversion with typo cases as `Attribute<float> attr(0.0f), Attribute<int> attr2(42); decltype(attr2)::value_type = attr.get();`. It is not more secure, it is just more verbose, and doesn't solve neither the case for C++03 (as `auto` and `decltype` are only for C++11 and superior).